# Generate Excel sheet from datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I have the datatable with data. Some cells have null values. I want to create the excel sheet from this datatable in C# + asp.net . I am using VS 2008.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/writing-data-from-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OfficeWriter is a third party API product designed for this task:

http://www.officewriter.com

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about formatting you can just write it out as a tab-delimited file.

Comment: Also `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";` and `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"file.xls\"");` should have browsers recognize that it's excel and have it open up in that